# Magento 1 product and Magento 2 as Checkout

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, checkout, payment, magento-connect

Is it possible to connect to two different Magento sites?

**1.** The first site has product details and purchased details. (in Magento 1.9)

**2.** The second site has a checkout and payment process.

Comment: Consider 'performance tuning' M1 single instance to achieve higher capacity with existing equipment to avoid all the 'sync' considerations and effort.  Please view my profile, Network profile for contact info and free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible?
In  theory it is possible. You can view the 2 magento instances as 2 microservices.
How can it be done?
Bypass all the quote validations soyou can proceed to checkout and do the checkout process. But this is easier said than done.
Is it worth it?
I don't think so.
Maybe it is easier to sync the catalogs betwern the 2 instances.

Answer (score 0):

Since the First Site's (M1) Primary-Duty is to host/manage Product Data and the Second Site's (M2) Primary-Duty is to serve as the Checkout and Payment Processing engine  - I think one could make the assumption that the M1 serves as your "Item-Master-System".

***Corollary:*** Your M2 site serves as your "ECommerce-Order-Master" and a "Item-Slave-System"

If my assumption (above) is accurate - Implementing your requirement is very similar to the typical Magento EE Implementation at most (mid-sized to large) Clients that need Magento to cater to their B2C operations - i.e. They have an Existing ERP-System (Oracle EBS / SAP / SalesForce / NetSuite / etc) which handles PLM (Product-Lifecycle-Management) / Order-Fulfillment / Operational functions - which they wish to continue to leverage.

Given this background - to achieve your requirement - all you really need to do is Build an ETL (Extract-Transform-Load) Process that can Sync Product Data from the Item-Master-System (M1) into the Item-Slave-System(s) (M2):

- It can be as simple as a `Scheduled Export of Products` from the M1 system and `Schedule Import of Products` on the M2 ....

OR

- As Complex as sourcing Product Information from the M1 system, in Real-time (via REST/SOAP APIs) with some sort of short-term-caching-mechanism (for performance reasons) in the Requisite Order2Cash Flows (CMS/Product-Listing-Pages/Product-Details-Pages/Shopping-Cart/Order-History/etc)

A few additional things to think-through when you design/build your ETL Process:

- What does your ETL Process need to look like? Are there multiple systems that need to be part of this ETL Process?

  - For Simple (i.e. Only-One-Master-And-One-Slave) ETL Processes - it might be more cost-effective to use a Schedule-Based (E.g: Cron-Jobs) processes for your ETL operations.
  - For Complex (i.e. You need to configure Business-Rules that allow for If-This-Then-That scenarios and/or there are Multiple Masters/Slave Systems) you might be better of using a Workflow-Based Orchestration-Tool (E.g: Jitterbit / Dell Boomi) for your ETL Operations.
- How large is your Product catalog?

  - If you have a LARGE catalog (10K+) - Processing Product Updates - via a CSV Export/Import process - and the subsequent Re-Indexing Operations MAY be expensive and/or affect the Customer-Experience on the Frontend.

    - You might be able to offset this risk/impact by scheduling your ETL processes during Non-Peak hours.
- How quickly should Product Updates from M1 be sync into M2?

  - If you can afford to 'wait' to Sync Product Data between systems - running a Scheduled Product Export CSV on M1 and a Scheduled Product Import CSV on M2 once a day might be the most cost-effective as that functionality exists OOTB in Magento and/or can be achieved with cost-effective 3rd party modules (MAGMI/FireBear/etc)

    - If you need to run this Product-Sync process multiple-times a day - you should think through how to handle Exception-Scenarios like:

      - How to prevent File-name Clashes.
      - What should I do if the Previous Export/Import Failed / Didn't-Run / Had-Processing-Errors / etc.
      - If there are multiple files that need to be Sync'ed - in what Sequence should they be Processed - FIFO, LIFO, etc.
      - Who should be Notified in the event of Successful Export/Import Operations.

        - If this notification is sent out daily - will it might become white noise?
      - Who should be Notified in the event of Unsuccessful Export/Import Operations.

        - What Actionable Data needs to be in those Notification Emails.
  - If you need updates to be Sync'ed in Real-Time - you may be able to create an Event-based Webhook mechanism - on your PLM System (M1) side - that updates Product Data on the target system - i.e. the E-Commerce (M2) side - if/when updates occur.
- How often does product data change (E.g: Product-Pricing/Inventory-Levels/Images/UPC-Codes/etc) on your PLM system (M1)?

  - If using the CSV ETL Approach:

    - If You have SMALL VOLUME of Product Data that Changes - it might make sense to only Sync AFFECTED Product Data everytime the Product-Sync occurs.
    - If You have LARGE VOLUME of Product Data that Changes - it might make sense to Send over ALL Product Data everytime the Product-Sync occurs.
  - If using the WebService Approach:

    - If You have SMALL VOLUME of Product Data that Changes - you could leverage an Event-Driven-Architecture approach (M1 and M2 both use event that you can hook on) and WebServices (M1 and M2 has a lot of OOTB REST APIs that you should be able to leverage for Product Updates)
    - If You have LARGE VOLUME of Product Data that Changes - to avoid Sync failures - you should consider using an Async/MessageQueue-based approach to the ETL operation.

I hope this helps!

Feel free to send me a DM if you have more questions and/or need a sounding board to bounce ideas ! =]

Cheers,

***Sharath***